# Why Does The Print Statement "=>" Come after you type in Input For The Scanner

Tags: java, input

I am trying to create a text based adventure game and I am trying to add a feature where whenever the game requires your input, a little tick mark, "=>" will show next to where you put your input. With this code here, whenever I run it in Command Prompt (Windows 7), the input shows up and the little tick doesn't. After you put in your input, the tick then shows up, after the input. I would like to be able to have the tick mark and the input all on one line like this, "=> [use input]". Please Help!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;



public class Game {

    public static String BLACK = "\u001B[0;30m";
    public static String RED = "\u001B[0;31m";
    public static String GREEN = "\u001B[0;32m";
    public static String YELLOW = "\u001B[0;33m";
    public static String BLUE = "\u001B[0;34m";
    public static String MAGENTA = "\u001B[0;35m";
    public static String CYAN = "\u001B[0;36m";
    public static String WHITE = "\u001B[0;37m";

    public final static String ESC = "\033[";

    public static String name;
    public static String gender;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnsiConsole.systemInstall();

        check();
    }

    public static void start() {

        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("###############################################################################");
        System.out.println("#                                                                             #");
        System.out.println("#                        " + YELLOW + "^.^" + WHITE + " " + "Adventure Time Is Yes " + YELLOW + "^.^" + WHITE + "                        #");
        System.out.println("#                                                                             #");
        System.out.println("###############################################################################");

        //Get Name
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("Hello young lad! What is thy " + RED + "name " + WHITE + "you were given at birth?");
        System.out.print("=> ");
        //Global Variable for Name
        name = a.next();

        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.println("Hello " + RED + name + WHITE + "! Are you a Male or Female?");
        System.out.print("=> ");
        gender = a.next();


    }

    public static void check() {

        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Can you see these colors?: ");
        System.out.println(RED + "Red " + GREEN + "Green " + YELLOW + "Yellow " + BLUE + "Blue " + MAGENTA + "Magenta " + CYAN + "Cyan " + WHITE + "White");
        System.out.println("Y/N");
        System.out.print("=> ");

        String as = a.nextLine();
        as.toUpperCase();

        if (as == "Y") {
            System.out.println(ESC + "2J");
            start();
        } else {
            System.out.println(ESC + "2J");
            start();
            //Future idea is to make it so there is an exact copy of the game but without color :D
        }

    }
}

/*try {
System.in.read();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

System.exit(0);*/

//System.out.println(ESC + "2J"); Clear Lines On Screen
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flush the output stream using outputstreamName.flush() . For more help see [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/outputstream_flush.htm) or [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).

Flushing your output stream will help you to find out where your code fails.

Comment: I am not trying to print to a file, I am trying to print to the console. So by using the outputstreamName.flush() wouldn't be available correct?

Comment: Incorrect. The flush operation can be called against any buffered output stream, and should be called whenever you want to make sure the buffer has been completely processed through to the output. Your question is a perfect example of why one might want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Flush the output stream, to make sure everything written has gotten all the way through the buffers, before you ask for input.

Comment: How exactly would I go about flushing the output stream?